# $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{E}_2)$ with (x,y) $\mathcal{R}$ (x',y') $\Leftrightarrow$ x' = x and y'=$\pm y$

Tags: general-topology

$\mathcal{E}_2$ is the euclidean topology. We have an equivalent relation on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{E}_2)$ with (x,y) $\mathcal{R}$ (x',y') $\Leftrightarrow$ x' = x and y'=$\pm y$.

I want to find whether or not the space $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{E}_2)$ with the quotient topology is compact or not. I think that it is compact because I then need to find an homeomorphism to the space H = $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert y \geq 0\}$ with the induced topology on H from euclidean so the space is (H,$\mathcal{E}_H)$.

I think that H is compact with the induced topology, so I want to say that the quotient space is compact as well. If I can find that the quotient space is compact then they would be homeomorphic with f(x,y) = (x,$\vert y \vert$) because it is continuous and bijective from a compact space to Hausdorff space.

Any hints?

Comment: How can $H$ be compact? It's not bounded.

Comment: @quasi How dumb! So I guess that even the quotient space is not compact. Is the function that I found useful for the homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, you can prove it's a homeomorphism, but you can't use compactness, so after showing bijectivity, you need to show that both the function and its inverse are continuous.